# ErrorCode:ServerError;InternalServerError on Azure IoT Hub connection

Tags: azure, curl, iot, azure-iot-hub

I try to send data to the Azure IoT Hub I created (better to the device in it) and get the following response (Postman):

{
    "Message": "ErrorCode:ServerError;InternalServerError",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Tracking ID:4c2417c4a2b14695bf869ba0902444c1-G:1-TimeStamp:05/07/2019 14:41:15"
}

My request looks like this:

curl -i 'https://$MYNAME.azure-devices.net/devices/testdev/messages/events?api-version=2018-06-30' -H 'authorization: SharedAccessSignature=SharedAccessSignature sr=$MYNAME.azure-devices.net%2Fdevices%2Ftestdev&sig=$MYSIG' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"deviceId":"testdev","temperature":70}'

and this is the response:

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error Content-Length: 155 Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 iothub-errorcode: ServerError Date: Tue, 07 May 2019 14:59:23 GMT {"Message":"ErrorCode:ServerError;InternalServerError","ExceptionMessage":"Tracking ID:b5936e5e08da45debfdba8a72f1c45dd-G:0-TimeStamp:05/07/2019 14:59:23"}

The SAS should be fine (recreated it several times and I also get authentication error when it is wrong).

I also created I new IoT Hub with a new device to test it without success.

Here are some details about my IoT Hub (sorry, it is German :)):

Status
:
Active
Standort
:
Frankreich, Mitte
Abonnement(Ändern)
:
Free Trial
Abonnement-ID
:
$XXXXXXXXX
Hostname
:
$MYNAME.azure-devices.net
Tarif und Skalierung
:
B1 - Standard
Anzahl von IoT Hub-Einheiten
:
1

Thanks in advance.

---

## EDIT:

all the capitals with $ are substituted from me to cloack security stuff

Comment: -H 'authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=$MYNAME.azure-devices.net%2Fdevices%2Ftestdev&sig=$MYSIG'

Comment: more details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security

Comment: Ok, the solution is: replace SharedAccessSignature=SharedAccessSignature to just SharedAccessSignature. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Roman Kiss mentioned:
replace SharedAccessSignature=SharedAccessSignature
to SharedAccessSignature

I don't know why there isn't an authorization issue with that but that works.